# No se genera mi base de datos SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de música para android y lo estoy desarrollando en `android studio`. Consigo mostrar y reproducir las canciones de mi dispositivo, pero a la hora de insertar los "paths" de dichas canciones en la base de datos, no consigo ni tan solo que se cree esta bbdd.

Sé que esta base de datos no se crea, debido a que el directorio "data" de mi aplicación se encuentra vacío.

Este sería el código de mi DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){ // constructor
    super(context, name, factory, version); // conecta con la base de datos
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `canciones`(" +
            "id_cancion INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  +
            "path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id_cancion`)" +
            ");"
    );

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `lista`(" +
            "id_cancion INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  +
            "path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id_cancion`)" +
            ");"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `canciones`(" +
           "id_cancion INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  +
            "path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id_cancion`)" +
            ");"
    );

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `lista`(" +
            "id_cancion INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  +
            "path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id_cancion`)" +
            ");"
    );
}
}
```

y esta la clase que instancia el DBHelper para crear la base de datos y hacer los insert correspondientes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
private String currentFile = "";
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //PREPARAMOS LA BASE DE DATOS PARA PODER HACER INSERTS
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this, "Songs", null, 1);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (null != cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
        setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
    }


}//FIN DEL ONCREATE

private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration});
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        ContentValues datos = new ContentValues();
        datos.put("path", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        db.insert("canciones", null, datos);

        /*
        * db.execSQL("INSERT INTO `canciones` (`path`) VALUES" +
            "('"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))+"');");
        * */

        name.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

        long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        double durationInMin = ((double) durationInMs / 1000.0) / 60.0;

        durationInMin = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue();

        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }
}// FIN MEDIACURSOR_ADAPTER

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

    currentFile = (String) view.getTag();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class); // fem un intent a Song
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("cancion_actual", currentFile);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    //finish();
}// FIN DEL ONLIST_ITEM_CLICK

}
```

Comment: Hola. El manejo de BD en Android parece de entrada complicado, y lo es mucho más si no usas un método claro. Hay varias cosas a tomar en cuenta que te facilitarán la vida más adelante. Te recomiendo este tutorial en el que se aplican de forma clara los diferentes pasos: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/01/base-de-datos-sqlite-en-android-con-multiples-tablas/ Es bastante completo y en español. Te explica cómo crear tu base de datos y hacer operaciones CRUD (Crear, LeeR, actUalizar, borrarD) en ella.

Comment: Muchas gracias, le echaré un ojo!

Comment: @Charlio podrías agregar si muestra algún mensaje de Error en el LogCat, me parece que pudiera ser un tema de permisos también.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios aspectos que revisar.

En primera podrías hacer algo así :

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
```

//Sentencia SQL para crear la tabla de Canciones y Lista

```
 String sqlCreateCanciones = "CREATE TABLE Canciones(id_cancion INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)";

     String sqlCreateLista = "CREATE TABLE Listas(id_lista INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)";
```

//Constructor

```
public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){ // constructor
    super(context, name, factory, version); // conecta con la base de datos
}
```

//Se crean las tablas

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //Se ejecuta la sentencia SQL de creación de la tabla
            db.execSQL(sqlCreateCanciones );
            db.execSQL(sqlCreateLista);
        }
```

P.d. Si no resulta o tienes más dudas con gusto te ayudo! :)

Te dejaré links con más info.

[Bases de Datos en Android (I): Primeros pasos](https://www.sgoliver.net/blog/bases-de-datos-en-android-i-primeros-pasos/)

[Una opción muy buena y potente REALM](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)